# IOS constraints - Shrink vertical spacing according to view size

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints

I have this view with a button and a label:

[image: open]

which is in a given size.

I want to make the spacing between the button and the label dynamic, meaning that when the view height is change, the spacing changes as well.

for a example:
[image: close]

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use three constraints:

1. Vertical distance between the labels. Use a greater than or equal to constraint and set it to 30 pixels or so. Set its priority to 1000.
2. Vertical distance constraint between the label and bottom of screen. Use a greater than or equal to constraint and set it to 30 pixels or so. Set its priority to 1000.
3. Center vertically constraint. Set it to center of screen (value of 0) and give it a priority of 999 or less.

This should get the behaviour you're looking for. By default, it'll center in the middle of the screen. Once it gets too close to your title  or the bottom of the screen, constraints 1 and 2 will come into effect and prevent it from overlapping or going offscreen.